# Github Gist Ghost Injection, Single Snipplet

Tags: github, gist, ghost

I have my blog made by 'Ghost', and I'm trying to inject Github Gist in my post using the javascript github provides.

However, I usually keep a lot code snipplets in a single gist.

```
https://gist.github.com/devlphj/6631dc284065a5e61752d3970d74303b
```

Like the link above, this gist contains 2 code snipplets.

However, I want to post only 1 of the 2 snipplets.

By the Github guide, normally you inject your gist like

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/devlphj/6631dc284065a5e61752d3970d74303b.js"></script>
```

However, by this method, both the 2 snipplets show on my blog.

I tried like,

However, this doesn't showed snipplets at all.

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? You can use a query parameter of `file=` for the URL.

When you want to embed `2.cpp` from [the gist](https://gist.github.com/devlphj/6631dc284065a5e61752d3970d74303b), you can use a following code.

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/devlphj/6631dc284065a5e61752d3970d74303b.js?file=2.cpp"></script>
```

When you want to embed `temp.cpp` from [the gist](https://gist.github.com/devlphj/6631dc284065a5e61752d3970d74303b), you can use a following code.

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/devlphj/6631dc284065a5e61752d3970d74303b.js?file=temp.cpp"></script>
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Perfectly answered my question!

Comment: @Hyungjoon Jeon Thank you.